# function call is not defined inside template literal

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a function like this, I'm trying to build a markdown editor

```
var Editor,
  __bind = function(fn, h) {
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(h, arguments);
    };
  };

Editor = (function() {
  function Editor(selector, options) {
    this.variable = __bind(this.varirable, this);
  }

Editor.prototype.variable = function(name) {
    this.editor.doc.replaceSelection('#' + name + '#');
    return this.editor.focus();
};

Editor.prototype._buildToolbar = function() {
    var $md = this;

$(`<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
  style="padding:0 0 0 10px;color: #000;box-shadow: none;height:100%;line-height:26px;">v</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" style="box-shadow: 0 0px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);border-radius: 0;margin-top: -1px;">
    ${Object.keys(this.options.vars)
      .map(function(key) {
        return (
          '<a class="dropdown-item" id="' +
          $md.options.vars[key].VariableName +
          '" href="#" onClick="variable(' +
          $md.options.vars[key].VariableName +
          ')">' +
          $md.options.vars[key].VariableName +
          '</a>'
        );
      })
      .join('')}
  </div></div>`).appendTo(this.toolbar);
};
```

The problem is that when I click on the link I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined` I've even tried to call it using `$md.variable(name)` but same thing.

Comment: `onClick="variable(' +
          $md.options.vars[key].VariableName +
          ')` this does not work due to the name of variable is not available in this context. You have to define that method to make use of it. Appending it to `Editor`s prototype will not work if you call the method that way

Comment: Could help me with that please, can you make a code on how to define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify `Editor`s prototype and it won't work the way you call the method.

Just change

```
Editor.prototype.variable = function(name) {
  this.editor.doc.replaceSelection('#' + name + '#');
  return this.editor.focus();
};
```

to

```
function variable(name) {
  this.editor.doc.replaceSelection('#' + name + '#');
  return this.editor.focus();
};
```

and your click handler should work.

greetings

**note**: `this` will point to what called `variable()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: in this case I need to see more of your relevant code. Is your code all in the same file? how is the JS Script imported etc...

Comment: where and how is the script included